# Adding a function to a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

In my JavaScript I have an object instance called "View". I want to add a function to this object. The function looks something like

```
function csiSelectValueRestriction (columnName) {
    //... <a rather long and involved function>
}
```

Ultimately I want to be able to use the function in the following way:

```
var result = View.csiSelectValueRestriction ("bldgs");
```

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the function to the property;

```
View.csiSelectValueRestriction = csiSelectValueRestriction;
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked great. It couldn't have been simpler - thx.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you want to add a function to an existing instance

```
View['csiSelectValueRestriction'] = function (columnName) { ... ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var View = {
   someProperty: 'someVal',
   csiSelectValueRestriction: function(columnName) {
        //JS logic
   }
};
```

or `View.csiSelectValueRestriction = function(columnName) { ... }`